# How can I test that all nodes in my SiteMap are valid in MVC3?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-4.0, nunit, sitemap

I'd like to write a (unit?) test to confirm that every node in my site's sitemap is valid. I have ~400 nodes, so it's obviously screaming to have a test written. Also, we're having some performance issues with the `SiteMapManager`, which [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13730304/294863) suggests could be because of a bad node in there. I'd specifically like to test to make sure that every controller and action handler in the file is valid (no typos, decommissioned/refactored names, etc.).

How would you do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a routing testing library (i.e. http://mvcrouteunittester.codeplex.com/) to chec if nodes in your sitemap are correctly routed to your pages (and not to 404 handlers for example).
Something like this:

```
 [TestMethod]
   public void TestSiteMap()
   {
      // Arrange
      var tester = new RouteTester<MvcApplication>();
      SiteMapNodeCollection nodes = LoadAllNodes();
      foreach (SiteMapNode node in nodes)
      {
         //check route results
         tester.WithIncomingRequest(node.Url)  ...//do your checks here
      }
   }
```

This is a possible implementation for LoadAllNodes if you are using Xml sitemaps:

```
 public List<string> LoadAllNodes(string siteMapFileName)
    {

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(siteMapFileName);

        var urls = new List<string>();
        AddNodes(doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes, urls);
        return urls;
    }

    private void AddNodes(XmlNodeList nodes, List<string> urls)
    {            
        foreach (XmlNode child in nodes.OfType<XmlElement>())
        {
            urls.Add(child.Attributes["url"].Value);
            AddNodes(child.ChildNodes, urls);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly would `LoadAllNodes` look like? That's one hurdle I'm not sure how to get past since it's a content file in a web app that's not actively being hosted.

Comment: I added a possible implementation in my answer

Comment: I'll try something like this later today or tomorrow. Thanks!!